# all my previous configurations and settings are gone by using the following command in ubuntu 14.04LTS

Tags: 14.04, command-line, delete, trash, rm

I used the command `rm -rf ~/.Trash/*` to empty the trash but when the command is executed, all my files in Download folder are deleted and all my Ubuntu settings are changed. Can anyone please help, how to get back my files and settings back?

Answer (score 1):

Gut feeling is you may have had a space after the ~. Is it really only the Download folder ? You should back up everything under home regularly. Add a new user with a similar name and tweak everything back, then copy their ~ to yours.